# Django - Summation of a column of a RelatedManager

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Posting/Voting site, and I am having trouble with the summation of votes.

Here is my vote model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    val = models.IntegerField()
    target = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Each vote has an integer value, and a target. Here is the Post model:

```
class Shout(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    content = models.TextField()
    def score(self):
        return vote_set.objects.aggregate(Sum('val'))
```

I am trying to get the sum of all of the vote val fields for each specific post. It isn't working.

Comment: You don't need to use `objects` for the `vote_set`. Just `vote_set.all()` will do, as `vote_set` is a `QuerySet`, not a model class`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a `self` reference to vote_set. Also, `aggregate()` returns a mapping, so if you just want the sum, you need to apply a lookup key. Finally, related managers don't use `objects` (That's the model manager)

```
def score(self):
    return self.vote_set.aggregate(sum=Sum('val'))['sum']
```